# Animations not working. Moving from left:0px to left :200px

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am a novice in html5 and css3 and I am just playing around with the different css3 animation features. Could anyone kindly point out the error in the code below? The movement from left 0px to left 200px isn't working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
        Experiment: animation with movements
    </title>

    <style>
        footer{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: red;
            animation: mymove 5s;
            animation-play-state: running;
        }

        @-moz-keyframes mymove {
            from {left:50px;}
            to {left:200px;}
        }
        @keyframes mymove {
            from {left:50px;}
            to {left:200px;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<footer>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to the `footer` CSS

```css
footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: mymove 5s;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@-moz-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 50px;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px;
  }
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 50px;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```